# An error in Null Value

Tags: sql

Please help me out in this as im getting an error:

> Divide by zero error encountered.
>   Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation.

Here is the code:-

```
(CAST(SUM(ISNULL(Cur.CurAmount,0)) AS FLOAT) - 
CAST(SUM(ISNULL(GLActualAmount,0)) AS FLOAT)) / 
CAST(SUM(ISNULL(GLActualAmount,0)) AS FLOAT) * 100 GROWTH_AMT
```

Comment: You have one error - "Divide by zero error encountered". (The other "Null value is eliminated..." is just information that some values sent to SUM is null.)

Answer (score 1):

I use `NULLIF()` in this situation:

```
(CAST(SUM(ISNULL(Cur.CurAmount,0)) AS FLOAT) - 
 CAST(SUM(ISNULL(GLActualAmount,0)) AS FLOAT)
) / 
NULLIF(CAST(SUM(ISNULL(GLActualAmount,0)) AS FLOAT) * 100, 0) as GROWTH_AMT
```

Answer (score 1):

Dividing by zero always gives an error.  I would add `WHERE ISNULL(GLActualAmount,0) <> 0)` to the end of your query, since if GLActualAmount is zero, your result is meaningless.